# overlapping navigation drawer and tablayout fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I am very new to android, I am currently making an app in java which contains a tablayout and a navigation drawer, when I click on the tab items of the tablayout the fragments work wonderfully!, but when I am in a fragment of the tabitem and I select an option from the navigation drawer, the fragments begin to overlap and there is no going back, hopefully you can help me because I don't know what else to do. I leave you my code to see if you can help me.

main.class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    NavigationView navigationView;
    //variables para cargar el fragment
    FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
    String personName;
    ViewPager2 viewPager2;
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
    TabLayout tabLayout;
    TabItem firstItem, secondItem;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);//se pasa el toolbar
        viewPager2 = findViewById(R.id.vp_horizontal_ntb);
        tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
        firstItem = findViewById(R.id.perfil_user);
        secondItem = findViewById(R.id.Debate);
        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer);
        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigationView);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.open, R.string.close);
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
        adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this);
        viewPager2.setAdapter(adapter);
        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager2.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.user) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager;
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
            fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content, new perfil_user());
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.friendslist) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager;
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
            fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content, new addFriends());
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

        } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.exit) {
            finish();

        } else {
            //pass
        }
        //aquí van las otros fragment
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return false;
    }

}
```

ViewPagerAdapter.class:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {
    public ViewPagerAdapter(@NonNull MainActivity fragment) {
        super(fragment);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                return new perfil_user();
            case 1:
                return new genera_debate();
            default:
                return null;

        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

main.xml:

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <include
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/drawer_toolbar"
        >

    </include>
    <include
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/content_main"
        >

    </include>
    <include
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/test"
        >

    </include>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        >

    </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>

    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

conten_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    >
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

drawer_header.xml:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:text="Menú principal"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:background="#0AA842"
        android:padding="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

drawer_toolbar.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="#067B30"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
/>

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tablayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/perfil_user"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Perfil de usuario" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/Debate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Debate" />

    </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/vp_horizontal_ntb"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you please put your layouts codes and you classes?

Comment: OK,editaré el codigo para agregar los archivos que pides (los más importantes)

Comment: I leave you the git repo in case you want to review it in more detail and run it:https://github.com/maurox521/appAndroid

Answer (score 0):

the layout error you have got is because the `navigation view layout` become in front of your `view pager layouts` so, I add a `frame layout` inside your main activity and this will give you a freedom to moving between layout without errors.

just check your new codes :

**Main Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
Toolbar toolbar;
NavigationView navigationView;
//variables para cargar el fragment
FragmentManager fragmentManager;
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
String personName;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);//se pasa el toolbar

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_container_,new a1_fragment()).addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();

    drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer);
    navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigationView);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.open, R.string.close);
    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
    actionBarDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
    actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();


   /* FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
    fragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction().setReorderingAllowed(true);
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, new perfil_user(),null);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();*/


}

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    if(item.getItemId() == R.id.home_item){
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_container_,new a1_fragment()).addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
    }
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.user) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager;
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container_, new perfil_user());
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.friendslist) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager;
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container_, new addFriends());
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.exit) {
        finish();

    } else {
        //pass
    }
    //aquí van las otros fragment
    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return false;
}

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_container_"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigationView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    >

</com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>



</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**drawer_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:title="Selecciona una opción">
<menu>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/home_item"
        android:title="Home"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/user"
        android:icon="@drawable/user"
        android:title="Perfil de usuario">

    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/friendslist"
        android:icon="@drawable/group"
        android:title="Lista de amigos">

    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/debate"
        android:icon="@drawable/stars"
        android:title="Debates">

    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:icon="@drawable/search"
        android:title="Buscar">

    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/exit"
        android:icon="@drawable/exit"
        android:title="Salir">

    </item>

</menu>

</item>
</menu>
```

**then I moved your `view pager` and it's nodes into a `fragment`**

**a1_fragment**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2;

import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem;
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;

public class a1_fragment extends Fragment {

ViewPager2 viewPager2;
ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
TabLayout tabLayout;
TabItem firstItem, secondItem;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup 
container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.a1_main_layout,null);

    viewPager2 = view.findViewById(R.id.vp_horizontal_ntb);
    tabLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
    firstItem = view.findViewById(R.id.perfil_user);
    secondItem = view.findViewById(R.id.Debate);
    adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this);
    viewPager2.setAdapter(adapter);
    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager2.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
    return view ;
}
}
```

**a1_main_layout.xml (the new fragment layout)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<include
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/drawer_toolbar"
    >

</include>
<include
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/content_main"
    >

</include>
<include
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/test"
    >

</include>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**after this effects you will have an item called `Home` inside your menu, it will let you to back to the main page because when you click on item from `navigation view` , a new fragment will be replaced in your main ui and when click on `Home` item your first ui will return**

hope I helped you !

Comment: hello friend, unfortunately it does not work with what you put, it gave me an error in this part of the code when passing it to a fragment: adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter (this);so I had to change the arguments received by the constructor of the pagerAdapter, I don't think that has affected
 (?). The other thing I realized is that in my original code I had an error, the fragment test does not do anything instead, it should be content as I left it now. Greetings and thanks for trying to help me

Comment: @Mauricio yes I forgot to tell you to change the adapter constructor argument type to : ` public ViewPagerAdapter(@NonNull a1_fragment fragment) {
        super(fragment);
    }`, anyway goodluck with your app!